# Can't get Build Success with Maven and C++ project in Hudson

Tags: c++, maven, hudson

I have a project in Hudson that is build with maven. It compiles C++ source code to create a an executable that is used in other parts of the project. It uses the Visual Studio tools, specially one that is causing trouble. When it tries to load the midl program it can't find it. If I log into the server were my Hudson lives and try to run mvn clean install in that particular project I get:

```
D:\Hudson\jobs\{project-name}>mvn clean install
.
.
.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.876s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 14 21:56:18 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (build-tlb) on project interop: Command execution failed.
Cannot run program "midl" (in directory "D:\Hudson\jobs\{project-name}"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified ->     [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR]     [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

A way to around this is to load the Visual Studio tools:

```
D:\Hudson\jobs\{project-name}>%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
```

After doing that I get a clean build:

```
D:\Hudson\jobs\{project-name}>mvn clean install
.
.
.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.331s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 14 21:59:06 PST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But this does not work when Hudson kicks of an automatic build. I tried to load that bat file (vsvars32.bat) performing:

```
pushd %VS100COMNTOOLS%
vsvars32.bat
popd
```

before I start the maven process, I know this is working because I see this in the console output:

```
C:\Apps\MicrosoftVisualStudio-10.0\Common7\Tools>vsvars32.bat
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
```

but whenever it gets to the point in which midl is actually used I get this output after the BUILD FAILURE:

```
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler - Build failed with exception(s)
[INFO] o.h.m.e.h.MavenExecutionResultHandler -     [1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (build-tlb) on project interop: Command execution failed.
[DEBUG] Closing connection to remote

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (build-tlb) on project interop: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "midl" (in directory "D:\Hudson\jobs\{project-name}"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified ->     [Help 1]
```

I also set the environmental variable pair {VS100COMNTOOLS,C:\Apps\MicrosoftVisualStudio-10.0\Common7\Tools} in the Hudson configuration panel. I do not know what else to do, any help will be apreciated.

Comment: I'm not hudson expert, but consider the OS user used to run hudson, maybe you got it working because you use a different OS user? Also check what the .bat does, could it possibly set something up on a separate shell instance when you did "pushd & popd", not on the current shell?

Comment: @gerrytan Thanks, the separate instance shell was a nice clue, I finally figured it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The way that Hudson calls new task is to call a new cmd window so the %VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat tools are set in a different instance. Looking at the mvn.bat in %MAVEN_HOME%\bin it lets you call a bat file before:
    if exist "%HOME%\mavenrc_pre.bat" call "%HOME%\mavenrc_pre.bat"
I called the %VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat there so every time we run maven the visual tools are also loaded. Nevertheless, it seems that Hudson does not start a maven task by calling that particular bat file, it somehow creates its own instance of maven, ignoring that mavenrc_pre.bat. A way to get around this is to create the task not as a Maven task, but as a batch task and simply call:
    mvn clean install
This solved my problem.